# Mysql Fetch Data From Two Tables Without Duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have two tables

```
table customers
cust_id  cust_name    cust_age    cust_level
-----    -----------  --------    ----------
1         raj           19             2  
2         ravi          22             3  
3         mani          20             4  
4         prem          41             1
5         kumar         34             2  



table emails
cont_id  cust_id     email_id          
-----    ----------  --------          
1         4           ravi@hi.com        
2         1           man@ji.com
3         4           ravee@ko.com
4         5           thee@lo.com
5         3           ras@ki.com
```

Now I want To Get list of customers where emails.email id LIKE 'r%' and list should be order by customers.cust_level ASC There Will not be Duplicate

```
my required ouptput is 

cust_id       cust_name    email_id      cust_level
-------       --------     --------      ----------
4             prem         ravi@hi.com     1
3             mani         ras@ki.com      4
```

Please have a careful look at table emails there we have two email ids for customer id 4, but we need only one entry of customer_id 4 [i.e no need for duplicate entries of customer id]
Can use any kind of join, distinct, group...

Comment: What SQL do you already have?

Comment: The point of SO is we help you when you have tried something - try to sort out a query & see if it works, if it doesn't post it here & you will get more help. A clue - have a look at SQL JOINS & GROUP BY.

Comment: @PaulF yes i have i way.... just go through the emails table and storing matching ids in a array... then check the array for duplicate entry.. then fetch datas from customer table through customer id... tht it... but i know this is not a fair way.... thts y iam asking a beter way here.... i have solution... but i need right solution

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables using a column that exists in both, and then return the columns that you want to display.

```
SELECT c.cust_id, cust_name, email_id, cust_level
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN emails e USING (cust_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  c.cust_id as custi_id, c.cust_name as cust_name, e.email_id as email_id, c.cust_level as cust_level
FROM
customer c
JOIN emails e ON (c.cust_id = e.cust_id)
WHERE e.email_id LIKE  'r%'
GROUP BY c.cust_id
ORDER By cust_level
```

That should do it, if you require all the emails of one customer in one row, add another field `GROUP_CONCAT('e.email_id')`